# python ipywidgets button color

Tags: python, button, ipywidgets

When using ipywidgets the way to create a button is basically as follows:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
layout_btn = widgets.Layout(width='200px')
mybtn = widgets.Button(description='load',
                       disabled=False,
                       button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
                       tooltip='this will happen:...',
                       icon='',
                        layout=layout_btn)
```

in the Layout object several things can be defined:
see here:
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html

Within all the layout possibilities I do not see the possibility of modifying the color of the button itself.

The question is how to make a button of a particular color (RBG or HEX)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

layout_btn = widgets.Layout(width='200px')
mybtn = widgets.Button(description='load',
                       disabled=False,
                       button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
                       tooltip='this will happen:...',
                       icon='',
                       layout=layout_btn)

# apply background color to the button
mybtn.style.button_color = '#90ee90' # or 'lightgreen' or 'rgb(144,238,144)'

mybtn
```

Returns

[image]

Follow the [link](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute) for more details about the style attribute.